# Single <Provider> for many components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following structure in my root component

```
<div className={styles.main_container}>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Topbar></Topbar>
  </Provider>
  <div className={styles.scene_and_tools}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Sidebar></Sidebar>
    </Provider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Scene></Scene>
    </Provider>
  </div>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Timeline></Timeline>
  </Provider>
</div>
```

This works fine but I find it a bit not so "DRY" to repeat `<Provider>` for every single component that I want to pass context. So I tried

```
<div className={styles.main_container}>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Topbar></Topbar>
  <div className={styles.scene_and_tools}>
      <Sidebar></Sidebar>
      <Scene></Scene>
  </div>
    <Timeline></Timeline>
  </Provider>
</div>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Provider`,
expected a single ReactElement. Check the render method of `App`.
```

Is there a way to make my code more DRY or I have to live with this redundancy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first variation is completely redundant. The only reason `Provider` exists in the first place is so that you can avoid passing the store down and explicitly. Otherwise you could just as well remove it and pass `store` as a prop to container components themselves.

The intended use case for `Provider` is to wrap **the rootmost component**. All children and grandchildren will then receive the store implicitly. You should only do it once, and put a single React element inside. Your second example does not work because you put three elements inside it: `Topbar`, `div` and `Timeline`. Wrap the outer `div` instead and it will work. Better yet, move `Provider` to the place where you call `ReactDOM.render()` and wrap your rootmost `App` component in it. Then you don't need it anywhere else.